# How to extract Datetime data from 'YYYY-MM-DD HR-MN-SEC' format to 'MM-DD HR-MN-SEC'' format?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am analyzing a time series problem and I Have data in **'YYYY-MM-DD HR-MN-SEC'** format.

I want to convert the data to **'MM-DD HR-MN-SEC'** format. In short I want to remove the **year** data. After conversion I want the data in **datetime** format , not as string.

I Have tried splitting the data, but it returns a string. I want the data in same format in the same column.
Here is the code I have below:

```
#slicing 2016 data

df8=df1.loc['2016',['humidity','pressure','temp']]

#removing outliers

df8=df8[(np.abs(stats.zscore(df8)) < 3).all(axis=1)]

df8.head()

                     humidity      pressure       temp

datetime_utc 

2016-01-01 00:00:00   100.0         1020.0         8.0
2016-01-01 03:00:00    94.0         1022.0        10.0
2016-01-01 06:00:00    51.0         1022.0        20.0
2016-01-01 09:00:00    32.0         1019.0        23.0
```

After conversion , I want the dataframe to look like this. Looking forward for help.

```
                     humidity      pressure       temp

datetime_utc 

01-01 00:00:00       100.0         1020.0         8.0
01-01 03:00:00        94.0         1022.0        10.0
01-01 06:00:00        51.0         1022.0        20.0
01-01 09:00:00        32.0         1019.0        23.0
```

Comment: I don't see how it could be in datetime format but not including year.

Comment: Like Rocky said, dates need to have a year. Otherwise how would pandas know if Feb 29 was a valid date or not? Do you want to remove the year for display purposes or something else?

Answer (score 0):

As noted, a `Datetime` has to have a year.  Certainly they can all be set to 0 and subsequently ignored.

But this question is about dealing with indexes over time by months, hours, etc.

Some strategies are to work with a `PeriodIndex` or `TimedeltaIndex`.  Or tolerate the data as strings.  Then there is `Grouper(freq=)`.

Here is a busy box.  Good luck analyzing your timeseries data.

```
import pandas as pd

# period index strategy
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [1,2,3,4,5]}, pd.to_datetime(["2000-03-31 00:00:00", "2000-05-31 00:00:00", "2000-08-31 00:00:00", "2000-11-30 00:00:00", "2001-01-31 00:00:00"]))
df.index = df.index.to_period("D")
print(df)

# timedelta strategy
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [1,2,3,4,5]}, pd.to_datetime(["2000-03-31 00:00:00", "2000-05-31 00:00:00", "2000-08-31 00:00:00", "2000-11-30 00:00:00", "2001-01-31 00:00:00"]))
timedeltas = df.index.to_series().diff()
df['timedeltas'] = timedeltas
df['days'] = df['timedeltas'].apply(lambda x:x.days)
df['hours'] = df['timedeltas'].apply(lambda x:x.seconds/3600)
df.set_index(['days', 'hours'], inplace=True)
print(df)

# string strategy
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [1,2,3,4,5]}, pd.to_datetime(["2000-03-31 00:00:00", "2000-05-31 00:00:00", "2000-08-31 00:00:00", "2000-11-30 00:00:00", "2001-01-31 00:00:00"]))
df['month'] = df.index.month
df['day'] = df.index.day
df.set_index(['month', 'day'], inplace=True)
print(df)

# time grouping
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": [1,2,3,4,5]}, pd.to_datetime(["2000-03-31 00:00:00", "2000-05-31 00:00:00", "2000-08-31 00:00:00", "2000-11-30 00:00:00", "2001-01-31 00:00:00"]))
data = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).count()
print (data)
```